# Scope of a dict in python

Tags: python

```
def taskCompletionCheck(self, jsonFile):

        json_data=open(jsonFile)
        data = json.load(json_data)
        json_data.close()
        wsTaskStatus = {}
        taskstatus = {}
        mydict = {}

        ''' Assuming the json file structure is similar to
        {"tasks":
            [{"name":"SA","result":"PASS"},
            {"name":"CR","result":"PASS"},
            {"name":"UT","result":"fail"}],
         "masks":{"id":"valore"},
         "om_points":"value",
        "parameters":{"id":"valore"}}
        '''
        for item in data:
            keyExists = data[item].get("auto-approve-plugin-status")

            if keyExists != None:
                for elem in data[item]["auto-approve-plugin-status"] :
                    mylist = elem["auto-approve-enclosure-names"]

                    mydict["status"] = elem["auto-approve-status"]
                    mydict["enclosure-names"] = mylist
                    taskid = elem["auto-approve-plugin-name"]+"_"+item
                    taskstatus[taskid] = mydict
        print taskstatus
        return taskstatus
```

When i declared mydict in a global scope (outside the for loop), taskstatus would not contain values of mylist , enclosure-names would only contain o's. Later i moved mydict inside for loop and it worked fine. Can anyone explain me what happened here?

```
if keyExists != None:
                    for elem in data[item]["auto-approve-plugin-status"] :
                        mydict = {}
                        mylist = elem["auto-approve-enclosure-names"]

                        mydict["status"] = elem["auto-approve-status"]
                        mydict["enclosure-names"] = mylist
                        taskid = elem["auto-approve-plugin-name"]+"_"+item
                        taskstatus[taskid] = mydict
```

This is how taskstatus would look like:

```
  {"CR" : {"status" : "fail" , "enclosure-names" : [a,b,c]}, 
   "UT" : {"status" : "pass" , "enclosure-names" : [d,e]}}
```

Comment: This code is invalid, there is a return statement but no function. I'd recommend copying the exact code that is giving you a problem into a separate file, and attempting to get it to run in isolation of the rest of the code. Once that is running, copy it into your question again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your original version, this code:

```
mydict["status"] = elem["auto-approve-status"]
mydict["enclosure-names"] = mylist
```

Every time through the loop, you are reusing *the same* mydict, each time overwriting the content you put there in the previous loop.

When you added `mydict = {}` inside the loop, each time through the loop creates a new, separate dictionary, and then you are not reusing or overwriting anything and it works properly.

Comment: Yes, i realize that declaring it outside is a bug, but it should atleast give me junk values right? why does it give me all 0's?

Comment: @user892871 oh I see; I can't tell. You have a typo in your quote about how taskstatus would look: `"enclosre-names"`. Where were the o's? How did you print/view them, how many were there, what pattern?

Comment: Hmmm. Ok. I edited my code. I was printing taskstatus just before returning it. It would print it this way.{"CR" : {"status" : "fail" , "enclosure-names" : [0]}, 
   "UT" : {"status" : "pass" , "enclosure-names" : [0]}}